# filter object in a functional way python 3

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I have a list of Note objects called `notesList`. I want to filter my list based on the property `codeCours` in a functional pattern using a lambda, where I only want to keep the objects having the same `codeCours`.

With a list of `Note` objects

```
notesList = [Note(numeroEtudiant=1, codeCours=11, note=14),
    Note(numeroEtudiant=2, codeCours=11, note=16),
    Note(numeroEtudiant=2, codeCours=13, note=16)]
```

I want to get all notes with a value for `codeCours` of 11:

```
[Note(numeroEtudiant:1 codeCours:11  note:14,
 Note(numeroEtudiant:2 codeCours:11  note:16)]
```

`Note` is constructed with

```py
class Note:
    def __init__(self, numeroEtudiant, codeCours, note):
        self.numeroEtudiant = numeroEtudiant
        self.codeCours = codeCours
        self.note = note
```

Comment: What does 'having the same codeCours' mean?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use filter and lambda, you can:

```
new_list = list(filter((lambda note: note.codeCours == 1), notesList))
```

Although I find a list comprehension much more readable:

```
new_list = [note for note in notesList if note.codeCours == 1]
```

Comment: is there a way where I can let the user input an id and note.codeCours == id

Comment: Of course there is. `the_id = int(input("Enter an ID: "))`, followed by `new_list = [note for note in notesList if note.codeCours == the_id]`

Comment: using the lambda way is there any method to do it like the one in the list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, just replace `1` with `the_id`.